# Why does my form error not show up in the template?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have a user login form

```py
class PersonLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)

    def clean_password(self):
        user = Person.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        if not user.check_password(self.cleaned_data['password']):
            self.add_error('password', 'That password is incorrect!')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

In there I check if the password is correct so that I can let an error message appear in the template
I access the error message in my template like so

```html
<div class="field-wrapper">
     {% render_field form.password.errors %}
     {% render_field form.password.label_tag %}
     {% render_field form.password placeholder='password...' type='password'%}
</div>
```

but The error message does not show up!
This is the view for the login form

```py
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'Successfully logged in!')
                return redirect('all_users')
        print(form.errors)

    form = PersonLoginForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': 'Login',
    }
    return render(request, 'index/login.html', context)
```

I print it after `form.is_valid()` evaluates to `False`

```html
<ul class="errorlist"><li>password<ul class="errorlist"><li>That password is incorrect!</li></ul></li></ul>
```

It doesn't even show up in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add this new form form = PersonLoginForm() to else statement when your request method is GET to keep having an empty form. By adding the else statement you avoid the new assignment of the form; after the validation process, it will jump to render(request,....) with the form instance containing all validation errors

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PersonLoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully logged in!')
            return redirect('all_users')
    print(form.errors)

else:
    form = PersonLoginForm()
context = {
    'form': form,
    'title': 'Login',
}
return render(request, 'index/login.html', context)
```